# How to concatenate multiple hex values to one

Tags: c++, qt, hex

I'm using QStringList to read hunderts/thousends of lines from config-file. I want convert 4 Strings from every row to 4 hex-values, concatenate this values to one hex-value and send it via UART to (STM32) uC.

Example: 
Read from config: **1200,1200,1200,1200** -> split at comma: 1200 1200 1200 1200 -> convert to Hex: 04B0 04B0 04B0 04B0 -> concatenate hex values: **04B004B004B004B0**

```
if(lines.at(i).contains(",")){
      while(lines.at(i+j) != "\n"){
      QStringList speed_chunks = lines.at(i+j).split(",");
      uart = speed_chunks.at(3)+speed_chunks.at(4)+speed_chunks.at(5)+speed_chunks.at(6)+"\0";

    m1 = speed_chunks.at(3).toInt();
    m1h = QString::number(m1, 16).toUpper();

    m2 = speed_chunks.at(4).toInt();
    m2h = QString::number(m2, 16).toUpper();

    m3 = speed_chunks.at(5).toInt();
    m3h = QString::number(m3, 16).toUpper();

    m4 = speed_chunks.at(6).toInt();
    m4h = QString::number(m4, 16).toUpper();

    uart_hex = m1h+m2h+m3h+m4h +"\0"; WRONG!!!
    //m1hm2hm3hm4h needed, not plus function!

qDebug()<<uart_hex;

m_serial.write(uart()); ?

                               }
                                 }
```

That is the simple way to do it? Thank you very much!

Comment: are there always leading zeros in your input?  such as 0001,0022,1111,0100?

Comment: Concatenating strings is obvious `"0001" "0002"`  is `"00010002"`. But "hex values" suggest integers, and concatenating integers makes much less sense. The number 01 is the same as the number 1.

Comment: Hello, there are different PWM values between 1000 and 2000. The PWM values are for 4 motor speed controller. Every motor speed controller get every 100ms another value, so there different combination possible: 1245,1587,1698,1478....

Comment: So I want changing a Values to hex first: 1245 to 04DD, 1587 to 0633... -> and then concatenating to 04DD0633... -> and then send the values.

Answer (score 0):

To print the result, you can use a combination of [std::hex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)  and an `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream stream;
QStringList items = lines.at(i+j).split(",");
for (auto str : items) {
    const auto trimmed = str.trimmed();
    const auto number = trimmed.toInt();
    stream << std::hex << number;
}

const auto result = stream.str();
std::cout << result;
```

This will print:

```
4b04b04b04b0
```

You can try to convert back the result into an integer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it. Another question about sending via UART to uC -  4b0 4b0 4b0 4b0 its still 8 Bytes (4b0 = 04b0?) or zero will be deleted and my uC receive just  4b04 b04b 04b0 (so just 6 bytes length)?

Comment: @Fracture I am not pretty sure. I just did a test with an RS232 simulator and I received  "4b04b04b04b0"

Comment: Error 1: aggregate ‘std::stringstream stream’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined   std::stringstream stream;

Comment: Error 2:  ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’ std::cout << result;

Comment: Have I do the conversion or declare std in QT? How?

Comment: std is the namespace of the standard library. You should include the sstream (std::stringstream) and iostream (std::cout).